# Python list reversed can't be accessed more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

Can someone explain this to me?

```
import numpy as np

arr = reversed(np.arange(11))

print(list(arr))


print(list(arr))

print(list(arr))
```

the output of this code is :

[image]

why can't I access the arr variable more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reversed` returns an [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). When you first call `list` on it, you iterated on it till the end and it has nothing to give back anymore. So if you call `list` again, it immediately says "stop iteration" and you get an empty list.

Fix is to store it when you first call `list` on it:

```
>>> arr = list(reversed(np.arange(11)))
>>> arr
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Though, in numpy's context you wouldn't cast to `list` but reverse in numpy domain:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(11)[::-1]
```

or

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10, -1, -1)
```

or

```
>>> arr = np.flip(np.arange(11))
```

or

```
>>> arr = np.flipud(np.arange(11))
```

to get

```
>>> arr
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])
```

Comment: Is there a way of resetting the iterator or are they only one shot objects?

Comment: @DrBwts One shot yes. Once exhausted (if ever), you need to re-generate. Or you can use something like `itertools.tee` to begin with more than 1 generator.

Answer (score 1):

The `reversed` method

> Return a reverse iterator over the values of the given sequence

Once the iterator is consumed, it's empty

---

If you consume it and store in a list, then you can use it multiple times

```
import numpy as np

arr = list(reversed(np.arange(11)))
print(list(arr))  # [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
print(list(arr))  # [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
print(list(arr))  # [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the return of `reversed()`. You anticipate that it is a list, but it is an iterator

```
import numpy as np

arr = reversed(np.arange(11))

>>> print(list(arr))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> print(list(arr))
[]
>>> print(list(arr))
[]
```

After the firt run, the iterator is empty. You can prevent this by creating a list from the iterator and then print it:

```
arr2 = list(reversed(np.arange(11)))
>>> print(list(arr2))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> print(list(arr2))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> print(list(arr2))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: You don't have to convert to `list` in printing out. You converted it in the first line `arr2 = list(reversed(np.arange(11)))`

Comment: I know, and you are right of cause. I just wanted to use the same print as OP...